# CFGRID not populating with data after upgrade to CF9.0.1

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

On CF9, this CFGRID worked fine, at least, it displayed fine (I had other issues with it).

After the update to 9.0.1, its completely blank.  I even tried the hotfix, no change.  I am dumping the query named "financedetails" above this code and it is showing data.  Any ideas?  Did cfgrid change substantially in 9.0.1?  Or can I no longer use the query attribute for an html cfgrid?

```
<cfform action="financials.cfm?showid=#url.showid#" style="margin-top:15px;" method="post">
    <cfinput type="hidden" name="showid" value="#url.showid#">
    <cfgrid query="financedetails" name="finance_grid" format="html" selectmode="edit" insert="yes" delete="yes">
        <cfgridcolumn name="Date" type="date">
        <cfgridcolumn values="chargeid" name="chargeid" display="false">
        <cfgridcolumn values="Setup Fee,blahh,blah,Custom Changes" name="Description">
        <cfgridcolumn name="Amount">
        <cfgridcolumn name="InvoiceDate" type="date">
        <cfgridcolumn name="PaidDate" type="date">
        <cfgridcolumn name="Notes">
    </cfgrid>
<p><input type="submit" value="Save Changes"></p>
</cfform>
```

Comment: any error in reported in firebug / chrome?  debug it like how you'd debug an ajax app

Answer (score 0):

This might because coldfusion 9 was using ExtJs 3.0 which is upgraded to ExjtJs 3.1 for coldfusion 9.0.1.

Check following should resolve it.

1. If you just updated to 9.0.1 then it may possible that js taking from browser cache which is version 3.0 causing this issue. Try to clear browser cache and try again.
2. Make sure you are not not using dflat/gzip on server side if so then clear file from server as well.
3. If you modified grid to add header or footer then you need to look for compatibility. check http://www.cfminds.com/post.cfm/updating-coldfusion-9-0-0-to-9-0-1
4. To make sure correct version of extjs.js is downloading, open firebug script tab and check the source of extjs.js and look into comment it should say version 3.1.0 instead of 3.0.0.

I think above four check will solve your issue.

-Pritesh